# Add Python to the Windows path

Tags: python, windows, path

If I forget to add the Python to the path while installing it, how can I add it to my Windows path?
Without adding it to the path I am unable to use it. Also if I want to put python 3 as default.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `Path` in `Environment Variables`

Add Python's path to the end of the list (these are separated by ';').

For example:

> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;
>
> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

and if you want to make it default

you have to edit the system environmental variables

edit the following from the Path

> C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27

Now **Python 3** would have been become the default python in your system

You can check it by `python --version`